# Is "fatty" a proper word to use?

Tags: politeness, connotation, colloquialisms

The most intuitive word to describe a person rich in fat seems to be *fatty*. However, I'm not sure whether it's commonly used in a derogatory sense in English. Do I need a more appropriate word instead?

I would like the most common term to use in an everyday situation. For example, to tell a person from a group of people:

> Tom: Who is Jack?
>   Jerry: The [fat/fatty/obese/...] guy over there.

Is calling someone *fatty* OK?

Comment: "Fatty", when used to describe a person, is a noun which means "a fat person".  It is very derogatory, as it is a "schoolyard" term.  Simply saying "a fat person" is slightly less derogatory.  "Obese" is an adjective (and the medical term) that is somewhat more "neutral" (if any such term can be "neutral").

Comment: (Of course if you simply mean a female who has some well-placed fat deposits in all the "right" places, there are a host of different terms for that.)

Comment: Thank you, @HotLicks. I think *obese* may be too formal but it looks like *fatty* is even worse. I just added a use case. Is *fat* the best choice here? BTW, the [urban](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fatty) sense of *fatty* has outgrown my English level...

Comment: As mentioned, "fatty" is not used as an adjective when describing people. The adjective is "fat." Commenting on someone's weight to identify them is unlikely to come across as appropriate no matter how you phrase it, but if you do it anyway, it's safest to use a euphemism (although [euphemisms may also annoy some people](http://www.bigfatblog.com/im-not-fat-im-euphemism)) or as Cargill suggests, simply the word "big" (assuming the person is not noticeably short). It's better to identify people using things like hair color, presence or absence of a beard, shirt color, or other clothing details.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, identifying a person is hard. If you use a bad word then it's derogatory. If you use a good word then it's still bad for those not being selected (e.g. *No, I mean the slender girl.*). So I'm wondering whether you know about a neutral word which describes this characteristic objectively and is commonly used as so.

Comment: Even though “the fat guy over there” is the easiest, clearest identification one often finds oneself saying, “the guy just to the right of the girl in the bright pink dress.” “Oh, you mean the fat guy?’. “Yeah.”

Comment: Heavily-built, or even well-built are neutral descriptive terms.

Comment: Unless you're talking to a friend and joking (and your friendship can take that sort of humour), "fat" and "fatty" (especially) are pretty much *never* acceptable. You can say someone is a "big" person, a "heavy" or "heavyset" person (which are much less inflammatory), but again, these have to be used with caution.

Comment: Obese is definitely a medical term which signals health problems. The common, most neutral term is **overweight**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fatty* is a taunt thrown at a fat person, just like *fatso*.  Reserve the word for biological and medical terms:  [**fatty** tissue](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fatty+tissue), [**fatty** acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid), [**fatty** liver](http://www.webmd.com/hepatitis/fatty-liver-disease).

Not to be confused with the slang usage, also spelled *fattie*, a [marijuana cigaret](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/fatty), as in

> Don't bogart that **fattie**; pass it along.

Answer (score 2):

*Do I need a more appropriate word instead?*

Difficult to answer without knowing the context in which you need a word for such a person.

(But after your edit, the least derogatory word for that situation is probably "big").

And "fatty" is not only derogatory, it is also infantile-schoolyard in almost all respects, outside medicine / chemistry.

Comment: A "big" thank you for this. Just a question: If one person has a greater width while the other one has a great height, will the listener understand "big" correctly in this case?

Comment: If there is a big wide person and a big high person to distinguish between the big-high guy would usually be called "tall".

Comment: Certainly I'd use "tall" if I mean the big high person. But if unfortunately I mean the big wide person, do you expect a need to quote your answer in case the listener tells me "they both look big"?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, *fatty* is an insulting term:

> fatty: an insulting word for someone who is fat

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fatty_2))

I would suggest **big guy** (mentioned by Cargill), **large guy**, or **heavy guy** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary link for [fatty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fatty?s=t) (courtesy of dicitonary.reference.com)

- **Fatty** can be used as a noun for a fat person
- **Fatty** as an adjective is used to describe meat, but not people
- To describe a person, the equivalent adjective is **fat**. However, this would usually be taken as derogatory or insulting.
- **Overweight** is less insulting, but people still don't want to be called it
- **Large** is an ok choice, in that it is *less* likely to offend... but people still don't want to be called it!

Comment: As an adjective *fatty* can be used for any food which is oily, greasy, or particularly high in fat. It's not only meat. *Fatty* I would say is used as an epithet towards someone you might know, rather than a plain noun. "I saw a large  man across the street" vs. "I saw  F/fatty across the street" (I know this person, that's my nickname for him)  vs. " I saw a fatty across the street" (any person of either sex who is overweight)